# Class error being thrown in PHP

Tags: php, reflection

I have NO clue why an error is being thrown with this code, any help please?

```
foreach ($config['commands'] as $commandName => $args) {
    $reflector = new ReflectionClass($commandName);

    $command = $reflector->newInstanceArgs($args);

    $bot->addCommand($command);
}
```

Error:

Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class Command\Resolve does not have a constructor, so you cannot pass any constructor arguments'

Comment: you have not construct in class so don,t need to pass args at object creation of class try $reflector = new ReflectionClass();

Comment: I don't think that will work, but let me try it.

Comment: doing that gave

     ReflectionClass::newInstanceArgs(): Internal error: Failed to       retrieve the reflection object

Comment: That's because some `$commandName` points to class that does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

I think the error message is pretty darn clear. [The documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.newinstanceargs.php#refsect1-reflectionclass.newinstanceargs-errors) also says basically the same thing:

> [Throws a] `ReflectionException` if the class does not have a constructor and the `args` parameter contains one or more parameters.

The class you're you're trying to instantiate **does not have a constructor**, yet you're trying to instantiate it as if it had one and are passing it arguments. `$args` should not be passed, or it should be an empty array. You need to make `$args` fit the constructor, currently they don't match.

```
namespace Command;

class Resolve {

    // Look ma, NO CONSTRUCTOR!

}

$reflector = new \ReflectionClass('Command\Resolve');
$command = $reflector->newInstanceArgs(['foo', 'bar', 'baz']);
// doesn't match the non-existent constructor ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I can run the same script on my home server with no error... it's just with my webserver... any reason why? I am using this script BTW: http://wildphp.com/

Comment: I don't know. Show us the definition of your class and what is in `$args`.

Comment: namespace Command;
class Resolve extends \Library\IRC\Command\Base{
protected $help = '!resolve <username>';
protected $numberOfArguments = 1;
public function command(){
$user = $this->arguments[0];
$user = preg_replace('@[^0-9a-z\.\-\:\_\,]+@i', '', $user);
$apiUri = 'http://website.com/'.$user.'';
$getJson = $this->fetch($apiUri);
$this->say(''.$user.' | '.$getJson.'');}}

Comment: that is the Resolve.php that it calls, I wish you could paste code in comments... -__

Comment: In reaction to wildphp.com: I think that in PHP5.3 passing an empty array threw an exception. This behavior has been changed in a later version